# setting up user roles within cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am new to Rails and am having troubles figuring out how to create user roles and then have it working with Cancan. I am following rails cast on this and the cancan wiki. What I don't understand to do is define each user role, for example what the admin, registered member and guest can access. I'm not sure if I'm on the right path or not with my coding. I have also run into a "undefined local variable or method `roles_mask'" error.

I don't believe I have the roles set proper in the below file. I have created user authentication from scratch if that helps any. The sections I have so far are galleries and user profile. ATM if I create a new account and select drop down box option "admin", I don't have any admin powers. I am still lock out of accessing pages.

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if @user && @user.role?(:admin)
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all 
    end

    if user.role? :user
      can :manage, Profile
    end

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, Profile
    end
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
  ROLES = %w[admin user guest banned]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
  end

  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ability.rb` file,

```
if @user && @user.role?(:admin)
```

should probably be

```
if user && user.role?(:admin)
```

Comment: Yeah I notice that earlier and have continued to switch back and forth, it doesn't change anything. ATM I don't understand how to assign true value to each user roles. I can create a account now, select admin...however I still don't have the admin privileges.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to set it through a form of some sort; have you tried setting it through the console, just to make sure that it does work? Also, just to check, your `User` table does have a `roles_mask` column, right?

Comment: Yes I have it set through a form. I have not done the console, to be honest I haven't even used the console yet for this project. I know I don't have the roles assign to hold a value.

Comment: If you've gotten an `undefined method` error for `roles_mask`, I'd definitely jump into the console and check that it's actually there and working -- that not being there would probably explain most of your problems. If you need any help doing that, let me know and I can run you through it :)

Comment: I am able to fix the roles_mask, as I needed to run rails g migration add_roles_mask_to_users roles_mask:integer. However I still don't think I am assigning value to the user roles I have created. Any advice with how I can do so? If you need to look at additional files please let me know.

Comment: How are you actually trying to assign the roles? If you don't think it's working, you need to work out exactly why -- is it a problem with the model itself (which is why I'd suggest you test it in the console, again, let me know if you'd like me to run you through doing this), or is it a problem with your form/controller. Also, do you want each user to have a single role or multiple ones? It sounds like a single roll if you're talking about a dropdown, but the pattern you've followed from the CanCan wiki is for a user having multiple roles.

Comment: I have been following railscast, wiki was only briefly used for when I ran into issues due to outdated syntaxs. Users will be having a single role. I am not too familiar with the console, help with that part would nice.

Comment: If you're only using a single role, you don't need a `roles_mask`, you should just use a `role` string column (check [this page from the CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization). If you're not familiar with the console, it's definitely something worth learning to use -- just enter `rails console` (or `rails c`) on the command line, and you can enter any ruby commands and see the results. For example, to test adding roles to a user, you could do `u = User.create()` `u.roles=["admin"]` `u.roles_mask`, where the last line should return 1 if the admin role is set

Comment: Thank you. The page you link me to provided me with the right solution. In ability.rb I needed to add: can :manage, :all if user.role == "admin"